# My Prestashop Website shows : "Error: "install" directory is missing"

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I copied my old website into a new one, but somehow, it's not working anymore and shows me : "Error: "install" directory is missing".

I configured my settings.inc file with my new DB altough.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check all files on /config directory.

Usually the reason for this problem is the incompleteness of any of the files in this folder.

Comment: Thanks it was that ! Silly me ^^"

Comment: Yea, but what to do with that files? Copy from other shop? Something more?

Comment: @Keso Usually the files in this folder (from version 1.7 and above) do not have any change and you can replace these files from the original version of Prestashop. But it is safer to restore a backup

Answer (score 0):

On PrestaShop 8 this error also occures when `'ps_creation_date'` field is empty  in `app/config/parameters.php`.

The solution is then to set a date formated as such :

```
'ps_creation_date' => '2024-01-19',
```

(It is supposed to be set automatically by the installer.)